# Maven multi-module project does not fail on compilation error

Tags: java, maven

I have multi-module maven projects such as proj-a, proj-b, proj-c. Among these projects, there is a project named assemler which basically creates a zip file for all the jar files generated by the pom of multi module project. The assembler project uses maven-assembly-plugin for preparing the zip file. My problem is that the pom file of the multi module project does not fail on  compilation error. Subsequently, assembler pom creates the zip file regardless there is compilation error or not. How can I stop the assembler project to create the zip file if there is a compilation error?

Here is the pom.xml of the multi module project

```
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>packer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>               
        <module>../../com.proj-a</module>
        <module>../../com.proj-b</module>
        <module>../../com.proj-c</module>

        ...........

        <!-- assembling all jars -->
        <module>./assembler</module>

    </modules>
```

the pom.xml of assembler is

```
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>assembler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projects</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.proj-a</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projects</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.proj-b</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.projects</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.proj-c</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-bundles</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>release-all-for-test</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>/src/resources/assembly-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And the assembly-descriptor.xml is

```
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

  <id>dist-assembly</id>

  <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>       
          <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
          <outputDirectory>/out-put/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <unpack>false</unpack>          
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Did you run with the command mvn clean package ?

Comment: You can also try with the following command mvn clean assembly:single.

Comment: Pu the assembly plugin code inside the parent pom.xml not inside the module assembler.

Comment: Do I guess correctly that your compilation failure does not fail the module build process? Because ordinarily if a module build fails in multi-module project all following modules get skipped. Also ordinarily a compilation failure makes a module build to fail - a compiler plugin should cause failure. You can try to make your module build fail when compilation fails.

Comment: @Sambit I did try to run with the command mvn clean package and putting  the assembly plugin code inside the parent pom.xml separately . However, none of them worked for me :(

Comment: @vitalyros Yes I think you guessed it right. Even if there is compilation error in one of the modules, maven creates jar files for all the modules - even creating the jar file of the module with compilation error. And finally, packages all the jars in a zip file.  However, the important thing here is Maven shows the compilation error on the log!

Comment: You should check the maven-compiler-plugin configuration in the modules proj-a, proj-b, proj-c and also their parent modules. It might have been configured to not fail on compilation errors.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#failOnError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the maven-compiler-plugin configuration in the modules proj-a, proj-b, proj-c and also their parent modules. The plugin might have been configured not to fail on compilation errors. It usually should fail on compilation errors. The plugin's option is called failOnError.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#failOnError